# Woocommerce meta data on single-product using function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filtering, meta

I am struggling with getting the meta data to filter properly through my functions.php.

I can get this to work if I edit the meta.php in my child theme with no problem:
[image: Works with meta.php]
(short story - but because I am using Avada Theme - and they change the location of the child theme on an upgrade, I am opting for the functions.php)

I am currently trying to filter the meta this way:

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_product_meta_start','add_pet_info' );
function add_pet_info($pet_info) {
$string ="Test Text";
return $pet_info . $string; }
```

And I would like to get this result:
[image: What I want]
But I just cant get it to work.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`woocommerce_product_meta_start`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/5893875b0c03dda7b2d448d1a904ccfad3cdae3f/templates/single-product/meta.php#L30) is not a filter. It's an action. So if you `return` a value to is, nothing is going to happen. This should print out "Test Text" before Woo prints any of its meta.

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_start','add_pet_info' );
function add_pet_info($pet_info) {
    _e( "Test Text", "your-textdomain" );
}
```

Unsure of where exactly you are trying to add the code, but keep in mind that you can add it to any hook available in WooCommerce (or any hook available in your theme).

For example to put the test text below the product meta you could modify the above to the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end','add_pet_info' );
function add_pet_info($pet_info) {
    _e( "Test Text", "your-textdomain" );
}
```

Anywhere you see a `do_action` you are looking at an action hook that you can attach functions to via `add_action()`.

Comment: If my assumption is right, the OP wants it below meta.. your code will put the text above meta.. if that's the case, there's `woocommerce_product_meta_end` hook for below...

Comment: That's what I thought too, and even tested that piece locally with `woocommerce_product_meta_end`. I left it at `start` since that was part of the original query, but will edit to explain that it can be moved.

Answer (score 1):

that area is handled by `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );`

so you could do something like this...

```
function rei_add_text_below_meta() {
   echo '<p>TEXT IN THIS AREA</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'rei_add_text_below_meta', 41 );
```

just play with the priority number... less than 40 will make the text appear above meta area.. 41 in this code will make the text appear below meta area.

Comment: Thank you all! This worked perfect!

Just to add a little context behind this...

I am opting for the "Function.php" route because Avada theme uses a custom file structure under woocommerce for compatibility reasons.

I originally had everything setup and running and then I did an upgrade and the meta.php and price.php vanished even though they were in my child theme.

Come to find out I had to add a "compatibility/version" folder in my child theme to get it to work again.

I feared future upgrades would continue to remove any customization.

Comment: ..and just in case this can help anybody else, here is some of the code I used.

' if (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_pet_status_select', true ) <> '' ) : ?>
   <span class="status_wrapper">
   <?php _e( 'Status:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
   <span class='status' itemprop="status">
      <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_pet_status_select' , true ); ?>
   </span></span><br>
 <?php endif; '
Thanks again!!!