# Woocommerce add custom buttons to product page

Tags: woocommerce, product

I would like to add two custom buttons to the product page below the category section. See pictured below:

Button examples:

[image]

I need to be able to set the button links on the product pages of Woocommerce.

Answer (score 1):

Below is very helpful website, which can you find product hooks:
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

You need to use hook:

> woocommerce_product_meta_end

And the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34694758/6844672